# Read database, put the text in two columns to fill them, and same the rest iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, layout

I want to build an app for iPad like a book, with two pages, with one column each.

After read some text from a database, I want to fulfill the two pages (with the right quantity of text), and save whats left to the next page. I will display some images between the text, and I need to make the text and image to fit in each page.

I'm thinking in use a UIWebView to hold the text.

My problem it's calculate the amount of text needed for each page and the text that left.

Can you help me doing that?

I will display some images between the text, and I need to make the text and image to fit in each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView is the wrong UI element to use if you just want to display text.  You should know that loading a UIWebView takes long and eats up a lot of memory.  This is a job for UITextView.

To calculate the text that will fit on a page, you will have to use the methods that UIKit adds to NSString.  Here is [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).  These help you to calculate the size a string will be when rendered with a certain font and certain line break mode.

```
CGSize renderedTextSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont forWidth:myTextView.frame.size.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

You could write a method that would use these methods calculate a substring of the text that will fit on your current "page" (UITextView).  Then, for the next "page", start from where you left off on the last page and add text to that string until it fits perfectly in your text view (maybe you add words until it gets too big to fit, then take out the last word and return that substring).

Something like that should work.

Comment: I forget to menchion that I will display some images between the text, so I cant use the the uitextview. So when I print some text, I need to consider the size of the image, that variate from image to image.

Comment: It sounds like you need a more complicated layout.  If you definitely want to use a UIWebView you will probably have to just create the HTML pages yourself and load those, rather than just reading the text from the database.  (I know JQuery can help you create a paginated layout).  Other than that I still think using UITextView (or a few of them) is the best way to go.  If you know where each image should be on the page you couple place the image, then load UITextViews around it.  (Like, if the image is centered vertically, make top and bottom text views, then calculate the sizes like above.

Comment: What do you think about canvas? Would it be possible to implement that layout in this king of application? I couldn't find many things about it. I think it have few documentation. But do you think that canvas should be an option in this king of application?

Comment: I don't know what kind of layout you're looking to create, but if you are just displaying text and images then you do not need to use a canvas.

Comment: I want to do something like a open book, and calculate which amount of text and images I can put in each page.